# Has an invalid "default" export: Type "Props" is not valid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm working on a layout page using Next.js. When I run the command `yarn build`, I encounter the following error:

```
- info Compiled successfully
- info Linting and checking validity of types ...Failed to compile.

app/[prefName]/create/layout.tsx
Type error: Layout "app/[prefName]/create/layout.tsx" has an invalid "default" export:
  Type "Props" is not valid.
```

Here's a snippet of the code that's causing the issue:

`app/[prefName]/create/layout.tsx`:

```js
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { lookupPrefecture } from "@/config/prefectures";

type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  params: { prefName: string };
  searchParams: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined };
};

export async function generateMetadata(
  { params, searchParams }: Props,
): Promise<Metadata> {
  // read route params
  const { prefName } = params;
  const encodedPrefName = decodeURIComponent(prefName);
  const prefectureName = lookupPrefecture(encodedPrefName);

  return {
    title: `${prefectureName} | Create Post`,
    openGraph: {
      images: ["/some-specific-page-image.jpg"],
    },
  };
}

export default function CreateLayout({ children, params, searchParams }: Props) {

  return (
    <>{children}</>
  );
}
```

compiled typescript type:

```js
// Check the prop type of the entry function
checkFields<Diff<LayoutProps, FirstArg<TEntry['default']>, 'default'>>()

// Check the arguments and return type of the generateMetadata function
if ('generateMetadata' in entry) {
  checkFields<Diff<LayoutProps, FirstArg<MaybeField<TEntry, 'generateMetadata'>>, 'generateMetadata'>>()
  checkFields<Diff<ResolvingMetadata, SecondArg<MaybeField<TEntry, 'generateMetadata'>>, 'generateMetadata'>>()
}
```

Error on the type

```
Type 'OmitWithTag<Props, keyof LayoutProps, "generateMetadata">' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [x: string]: never; }'.
  
Property 'searchParams' is incompatible with index signature.
    
Type '{ [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2344)
type Diff<Base, T extends Base, Message extends string = ""> = 0 extends 1 & T ? {} : OmitWithTag<T, keyof Base, Message>
```

Could someone please help me understand what's going wrong here? I'm not sure why the "Props" type is considered invalid in this context.

Comment: The compiled JavaScript you show is not in fact JavaScript at all

Comment: Function declaration looks good to me. Issue might be because of the filenaming maybe? With the new nextjs version you have to define file names with `page.tsx`? does the compiler gives any error in the runtime of the application on development server?

Comment: @M.G.SSUPUNTHAKA i made `page.tsx` in the same folder. I made layout.tsx so that I can generate metadata and i can use client components in page.tsx.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it compiled successfully:
Basically remove `children: React.ReactNode;` from Props

```js
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { lookupPrefecture } from "@/config/prefectures";


//URL parameters
type Props = {
  params: { prefName: string };
};

export async function generateMetadata(
  { params }: Props,
  // parent?: ResolvingMetadata
): Promise<Metadata> {
  // read route params
  const { prefName } = params;
  const encodedPrefName = decodeURIComponent(prefName);
  const prefectureName = lookupPrefecture(encodedPrefName);

  return {
    title: `${prefectureName} | Make Post`,
    openGraph: {
      images: ["/some-specific-page-image.jpg"],
    },
  };
}

export default function CreateLayout({ children }: {children: React.ReactNode}) {

  return (
    <>{children}</>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Metadata } from "next";
import { lookupPrefecture } from "@/config/prefectures";

type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  params: { prefName: string };
  searchParams: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined };
};

export async function generateMetadata(
   { params, searchParams }: Props,
): Promise<Metadata> {
    // ...
}

function CreateLayout({ children }: Props) { // Adjusted the props destructuring here
 return (
   <>{children}</>
 );
}

export { CreateLayout }; // Exporting CreateLayout
```

This code structure should fix your error, I made a minor change to the CreateLayout function by adjusting the props destructuring to only include children, since that's the only prop you are using within the component.

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't work. i still have the same type error. i think you need to export as default? but Adjusted the props restructuring was a good point, i made that change.

Comment: This is a non answer and doesn't compile!